# Validating guice module configuration - how to use the SPI?

Tags: java, validation, dependency-injection, guice

I'm writing a framework that uses Guice to bootstrap a server, and so I've extended Guice's `AbstractModule` to create a `Module` that provides some convenience methods for users to configure their code. However, I want to to check that the configuration is sane before launching the code. So it has to go somewhere in here:

```
// here, before the injector is created?
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(someModule);               
// here, after configure() is called?
Object something = injector.getInstance(SomeServer.class);
// start the server
```

It seems that there's not much I can check before the injector is created because the modules are not `configure()`ed yet. There is some mention of using the Guice SPI to validate module configuration, but the documentation is not too clear. Can someone, who uses Guice, give a short description on the best practices for validating modules before injectors are used?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't experienced much of this first-hand, but it seems to me that you have three choices:

- Refactor to `MyConvenienceMethodModule.myConfigure()` and `MyConvenienceMethodModule.validate()` if your convenience methods are expressive enough to provide useful information without ever running `configure()`. In theory you could call `Module.configure(Binder)` with a mock, but with Guice's EDSL that's far too complex; use `ElementVisitor` (below) instead.
- Call [`Elements.getElements()`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/spi/Elements.html#getElements%28com.google.inject.Module...%29) on a particular `Module` to check on the binding status. Because the elements might be of a variety of types, you'd probably want to create an [`ElementVisitor`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/spi/ElementVisitor.html) instead (probably by creating a subclass of [`DefaultElementVisitor`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/spi/DefaultElementVisitor.html) to insulate you from future Elements yet to be created). This way you get a good view of all bindings, even bindings in Guice's EDSL, while still in the context of the Module. **I think this is your best bet.**
- Create your Injector as usual and call [`getAllBindings()`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html#getAllBindings%28%29) to investigate it. This is probably your best option if your configuration's sanity depends on  how multiple modules interact, rather than how individual modules are structured. If you only check at this point, you won't really be able to tell one Module from another.